# Pig: how to compute quantiles for several variables in a Group By?

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera

I am using **Apache DataFu** 
(http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.3.0/datafu/pig/stats/Quantile.html)

to compute the **quantiles** of several variables in the data.

My undestanding is that the data needs to be sorted before calling `quantile`.

However, what if I need to compute quantiles for several variables within the same GROUP BY sequence? Given that the creation of the quantile variable occurs after the GENERATE, only one sorting (the last one) will be taken into account, as in this simple example:

```
 -- input: 9,10,2,3,5,8,1,4,6,7
 input = LOAD 'input' AS (val:int);

 grouped = GROUP input ALL;

 -- produces: (1,5.5,10)
 quantiles = FOREACH grouped {
   sorted = ORDER input BY val;
   GENERATE Quantile(sorted);
 }
```

works for one variable, but how can I modify this code if I want the quantiles for two different variables in each groupby?

say, if the data looks like

```
group col1 col2
A     1    2   
A     3    1
B     1    0
B     9   -2
```

for each group, I want the quantiles of col1 and col2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple `ORDER` statements in a nested `FOREACH`, for example:

```
x = FOREACH grouped {
  sorted_by_col1 = ORDER input BY col1;
  sorted_by_col2 = ORDER input by col2;
  GENERATE
    group,
    Quantile(sorted_by_col1.col1),
    Quantile(sorted_by_col2.col2);
}
```

Comment: very smart. I havent thought about the possibility of getting data from multiple sources in the `GENERATE` step